# Creating Filesystem on File that has definied size

Tags: ext4, mkfs

I know that when you make a new file and create a ext4 filesystem on it with `mkfs`, the filesystem will be smaller than the file because of the blocksize.
However, when I want to have a filesystem that has the size that I specified, how much bigger do I need to make the file in the first place?

Comment: Can you provide references for what you "know". Filesystems are created in partitions, not files. Blocksize is an attribute of the media -- how does it make a filesystem "smaller" ? The filesystem reserves some space for metadata (like inodes) so the sum of the filesizes (plus directories) is less than the raw space in the partition, but it seems unlikely you know the future contents accurately enough for this to matter.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, `mke2fs` will happily format a filesystem in a regular file and you can then mount it with help from the loopback driver.  `mount -o loop` will even take care of setting up the loopback driver for you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a number of factors including what options you pass to `mke2fs` and what version you are using, so you're really just going to have to experiment until you get what you want.